# Given a sequence $x_{n}$ in the metric space $(X,d)$, prove that $L$ is a limit point iff there is a subsequence $x_{f(n)}$ which converges to $L$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Let $(x_{n})_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of points in a metric space $(X,d)$, and let $L\in X$. Then the following are equivalent

(a) $L$ is a limit point of $(x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$

(b) There exists a subsequence $(x_{f(n)})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ of the original sequence $(x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ which converges to $L$.

**My solution (Edit)**

Let us prove the implication $(a)\Rightarrow(b)$ first.

Indeed, we have the following definition of limit point at hand:

for every $\varepsilon > 0$ and every $N\geq 1$ there is a natural $n\geq N$ such that $d(x_{n},L) < \varepsilon$.

Thus, if we choose $\varepsilon = 1$, there is a natural number $n_{1}\geq 1$ such that $d(x_{n_{1}},L) < 1$.

If we choose $\varepsilon = 1/2$, there is a natural number $n_{2} > n_{1}$ such that $d(x_{n_{2}},L) < 1/2$.

If we choose $\varepsilon = 1/3$, there is a natural number $n_{3} > n_{2}$ such that $d(x_{n_{3}},L) < 1/3$.

Indeed, for every $\varepsilon = 1/j$, there is a natural $n_{j} > n_{j-1} > \ldots > n_{1}$ such that $d(x_{n_{j}},L) < 1/j$.

Taking the limit, we conclude that $x_{f(j)}\to L$, where $f(j) = n_{j}$.

Now it remains to prove the converse implication $(b)\Rightarrow(a)$.

Comment: What is $f(n)?$

Comment: We define $f:\textbf{N}\to\textbf{N}$ to be a strictly increasing function.

Comment: You should mention it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof for "(a) $\implies$ (b)" is incorrect. You have found a bunch of points in the sequence that lie within the distance of $\varepsilon$ of $L$, but that does **NOT** mean that this subsequence that you constructed converges to $L$. By your construction, all of these points $x_{n_j}$ only satisfy $d(x_{n_j},L)<\varepsilon$ for **the same** $\varepsilon$. For all we know, it's quite possible that all of them lie more than $\varepsilon/2$ away from $L$. In other words, while all these points lie not to far from $L$, there's no guarantee at all that they are getting closer and closer to $L$.

To fix this flaw, you need to remember that the definition of limits points in metric spaces starts with "For any $\varepsilon>0$, …". And you really need to apply it different values of $\varepsilon$, which you can choose yourself — but make sure to make them smaller and smaller, to enforce the points that you choose to actually keep getting closer and closer to $L$. You can start with "Let $\varepsilon_1=1$; then we can find $x_{n_1}$ such that …". Try to take it from here.

Your reasoning for the other direction is also wrong. You didn't prove anything there … If you construct a correct prove for the first part, hopefully it will help you to start over on this part next. One of your mistakes is exactly the same — you only take one value of $\varepsilon$ (and even worse, you don't explain how you chose it). And then it looks like you picked only two points from the sequence. That doesn't prove anything.

**UPDATE:** Here's a more detailed explanation of how you can start a proof of "(a) $\implies$ (b)".

- Let $\varepsilon_1=1$ and $N_1=1$. According to the definition of a limit point, there exists an index $n_1\geqslant N_1=1$ such that $d(x_{n_1},L)<\varepsilon_1=1$.
- Let $\varepsilon_2=1/2$ and $N_2=n_1+1$. According to the definition of a limit point, there exists an index $n_2\geqslant N_2$ such that $d(x_{n_2},L)<\varepsilon_2=1/2$.

Can you continue from here?

Comment: I have tried to explicit my reasoning properly this time. Please tell me if it is still wrong.

Comment: @EagerToLearn: You still didn't fix the same main flaw: you're only constructing a subsequence for one value of $\varepsilon$. So for each $\varepsilon$ you construct its own subsequence, and there's no guarantee at all that any of them converges. Instead you must construct a single subseqence that converges to $L$.

Answer (score 1):

You already did it here:

[Prove that $L$ is a limit point of the sequence $(a_{n})_{n=0}^{\infty}$ iff there is a subsequence $(a_{f(n)})_{n=0}^{\infty}$ which converges to $L$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3677048/prove-that-l-is-a-limit-point-of-the-sequence-a-n-n-0-infty-iff-the?rq=1).

But the mistakes in both proofs are the same: for convergence you need to let $\varepsilon\to0$.

> Let us correct your first part (as an example), that is, for $(b)\Rightarrow(a)$, following your own text:

Take $n_0\in\mathbb N$ such that $d(x_{n_0},L) < 1$.

Take $n_{1} > n_{0}$ such that $d(x_{n_{1}},L) < \frac12$.

Take $n_{2} > n_{1}$ such that $d(x_{n_{2}},L) < \frac13$.

Proceeding this way, we conclude there exists a subsequence $x_{f(n)}$ which converges to $L$, where $f(j) = n_{j}$.

Comment: I will mention it on my question.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I've just checked out the OP's previous question that you linked to. Sadly, someone told the OP that their wrong work in that post was correct. No wonder that, after receiving such a terrible disservice, the OP keeps repeating the same mistakes...